# How to use ?: operator in java where one condition is lacking?

Tags: java, conditional-operator

I want to simplify this code:

```
++ index;
if(index > max)
  index = 0;
```

I try to write this:

```
++index > max ?   : index = 0; //java compile failed
```

How to do it?

Comment: index = (index > max ) ? 0 : index;
But, if you have trouble writing it this way, why refactor it? the code works as it is

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? `?:` makes an expression. And you can't have that just standing on its own.

Comment: I just want to reduce the 3 lines to a line, there is a lot of indexs to deal with.

Comment: If you're doing this a lot then creating a (private) helper method is also an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are trying to achieve is called the ternary operator. There are countless articles explaining it easily found with a simple google search. Here is one from geeksforgeeks: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-ternary-operator-with-examples/

Anyways, this is used to set a variable. You evaluate the condition, if it is true your variable is the first option, if it is false your variable will be the second option. Not sure if I am making sense here.

```
index = ++index > max ? 0 : index
```

Essentially this is asking: is ++index > max? If yes index = 0 else index = index

Although I am unsure in java whether the ++index will increment before the evaluation, if it does not you just have to increment it before doing the ternary operator.

Hopefully this helped.

Comment: Right, it works. Although the false-condition assignment is redundant. I wonder it can be perfect done in c++ ?

Comment: "the false condition assignment is redundant", no, it isn't. You can't use a ternary operator without that false condition assignment

Comment: Yea you do need that false condition else you'll probably get a syntax error. If you want to eliminate the false condition you can do a one liner like such:
`if (++index > max) index = 0;`
I think this might also work in java.